# My expect script will pass the userid but not the password what am I doing wrong?

Tags: expect

When I run the script it passes the **userid** to respond to the enter **userid** prompt,  when it is prompted for the password it fails.

I am a newbie with expect and would appreciate any help.

```
version=$1
targetPrompt=":"
if [ "$1o" = "o" ]; then
  echo "Syntax is getNewCode [gitrepo version]"
  exit
fi

echo "Enter your git userid"
read  userid
echo "Enter your git password"
read -s  mypassword
###################################################################
publicURL="https://hub.jazz.net/git/xxxxxxxx/cigsdev_mvpFE_$version"  
###################################################################
# Call setupNewDirectories to create new directories
/CIGS/setupNewDirectories
###################################################################
# CD to the directory where the public repository will be loaded 
#
rm -rf /tmp/FINAL
mkdir /tmp/FINAL
ls /tmp/FINAL | wc -l
cd /tmp/FINAL
#
###################################################################
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
spawn git clone $publicURL
expect "Username for *:"
send "$userid\n" 
expect "Password *:"
send "$mypassword/n"
expect eof
EOD
exit
```

Comment: To send `Enter` key, use `\r`. Your password should go with `\r` or `\n`. (though it is better to use `\r`)

Comment: To emphasize Dinesh's comment, you're not "hitting Enter" after you type in the password (plus 2 extra characters).

Comment: While you're debugging an expect script, use `/usr/bin/expect -d` to enable verbose debugging output.